# Launch flutter app which is in terminated or background state when FCM data message arrives (in android OS only)

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a video call app using Twilio in a flutter. I am able to receive FCM (Firebase cloud messaging) data messages. I just want to launch my app from within the `onBackgroundMessage`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am having this same exact issue... Were you able to find a solution? Since it's been 3 months since you posted this question.